# Grails Hibernate criteria - Checking if a relation exists

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm attempting to perform a filter to find if a certain object has a relationship with another. I had an object `Component`:

```
class Component { 
    long id
    String name
}
```

And a Component is used by a Page.

```
class Page {
    long id
    static hasMany = [components : Component]
}
```

How would I go about building a hibernate criteria to check if my component has a relationship with any page? One component can be used by many pages. So far, all I can think of is something like:

```
Component.createCriteria().list {
    inList("id", Page.list().components);
}
```

But that isn't going to scale very nicely at all. So I was wondering if there was a simpler way of saying "If my object is used by this object"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Page.createCriteria().count {
    components {
        eq("id", yourComponent.id)
    }
}
```

This query gives you the count of all the Pages which have yourComponent. And if this is 0 then there yourComponent is not associated to any Page.

**EDIT____________________________________________________________**

No, because `Component` have no relation with `Page`.

But if you want this then my suggestion is `formula column`. In this relationship you have three tables `component`, `page` and there relationship table `page_components`.

eg.,

```
class Component { 
    long id
    String name
    Boolean isRelatedWithAnyPage

    static mapping = {
        isRelatedWithAnyPage formula: "(select (count(*)>0) from page_components pc where pc.component_id = id)"
    }
}
```

Note:- I haven't tried this, may be you need to change the sql query in formula.

Comment: Is there a way to insert this as part of the first criteria?

Comment: I have edited my post. Have a look. Hope this helps.

Comment: Took a similar approach to your first suggestion so I figured I'll accept this one. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists with a subquery.

```
def subQuery = Page.where({
   components {
      eqProperty("id", "this.id") //this: is the root alias which refers to the Component
   }
   setAlias("page")
})


Component.createCriteria().list {
  exists(subQuery.id())
}
```

See [how to execute exists subqueries with grails criteria](http://nimavat.me/blog/gorm-hibernate-criteria-subquery-with-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a PageComponent domain to match the underlying join table that was created by grails automatically and do `PageComponent.countByComponentId(componentId)`

Comment: That's a good suggestion but it's not a convention we've followed in lots of other applications so I don't think that will pass code review! But thank you for the input and +1 for the logical suggestion.